# Is a for(auto ...) of list where we append new elements within the loop guaranteed to work against all the elements?

Tags: c++, list, for-loop, linked-list, stl

I have a class with an `f_next` field that looks like so:

```
class process
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<process> pointer_t;
    typedef std::list<pointer_t> list_t;

    void add_next_process(pointer_t p);
    void wait();

private:
    list_t f_next = list_t();
};
```

The `add_next_process()` simply appends `p` to `f_next`:

```
f_next.push_back(p);
```

As a result, the `wait()` has to gather all the processes and wait for all of them. I'd like to avoid recursion and instead generate a list of all the `f_next` like so:

```
list_t n(f_next);
for(auto & it : n)
{
    n.insert(n.end(), it->f_next.begin(), it->f_next.end());
}
```

Is `n` guaranteed to include all the items once the `for()` loop exits?

I know that [`std::list::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) does not change the iterator:

> No iterators or references are invalidated.

but I'm wondering whether the `for(auto ...)` will continue through all the items that I appended along the way.

Comment: I have found, in general, modifying a container or the container's contents while iterating over it is a fecund source of bugs and maintenance woes.  An order of magnitude moreso if exceptions are in the mix, while trying to maintain coherency and invariants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For-range is just a syntactic sugar for a classic for loop operating on iterators.
As long as your container implements begin and end (or you have free overloads), and don't invalidate the iterator in the process, this should technically be fine.
Other thing is whether this is a good and maintainable idea.

Before C++17:

```
auto && __range = range-expression ;
for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
  range-declaration = *__begin;
  loop-statement
}
```

From C++17:

```
auto && __range = range-expression ;
auto __begin = begin_expr ;
auto __end = end_expr ;
for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
  range-declaration = *__begin;
  loop-statement
}
```

Comment: Cool. That would mean the `std::list::end()` value never changes.